# How to get JMX port without ZooKeeper (with bootstraper servers only)?

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

We can get `jmx_port` using zk node `/brokers/ids/xxx`. Now Kafka is moving to a ZooKeeper-free architecture, how do we get this info with only bootstrap servers? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka is a Java process, so yes, it's possible.

There's an environment variable `JMX_PORT` used when the broker starts that you can ask your server administrators to set/document - https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.2/bin/kafka-run-class.sh#L213

Comment: The problem is that I might be using managed Kafka without access to the server, and I see many UI tools for Kafka rely on `jmx_port` property in ZK node. Also the `jmx_port` in ZooKeeper node is documented in the book *Kafka: The Definitive Guide* so I guess this is somewhat official and systems might depend on it, so I wonder whether there is a way to automatically get this info without ZK.

Comment: 1) The Definitive Guide has a new edition 2) KIP500 (removal of Zookeeper) isn't complete, yet, and isn't scheduled to be for at least end of the year 3) I'm not sure what UI you're referring to. Confluent Control Center / Confluent Cloud, as one example, doesn't need Zookeeper information to display Kafka metrics. Neither does Amazon MSK. You shouldn't need direct server access to set environment variables

Comment: Thanks for the info! I encountered this problem with https://github.com/yahoo/CMAK and https://github.com/smartloli/EFAK, both demanding `jmx_port`. Maybe in the final version of KIP500 this will be migrated into some configuration topic.

Comment: ...I meant they get `jmx_port` from ZK node, and the port number is currently not configurable in both apps. Amazon MSK would use a different port for JMX and this port was not updated to the ZK node, thus this question.

Comment: You'd need to create issues in those repos - for example https://github.com/smartloli/EFAK/issues/609 , but I would assume they'd migrate to using OpenMetrics (Prometheus)

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using it for kafka broker only, for prometheus. Added this line `Environment="KAFKA_OPTS=-javaagent:/kafka/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.1.jar=7080:/kafka/kafka-0-8-2.yml"` to systemd service file. You need to download jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.3.1.jar, of course.

And this is how the yaml file looks like:

```
lowercaseOutputName: true
rules:
- pattern : kafka.cluster<type=(.+), name=(.+), topic=(.+), partition=(.+)><>Value
  name: kafka_cluster_$1_$2
  labels:
    topic: "$3"
    partition: "$4"
- pattern : kafka.log<type=Log, name=(.+), topic=(.+), partition=(.+)><>Value
  name: kafka_log_$1
  labels:
    topic: "$2"
    partition: "$3"
- pattern : kafka.controller<type=(.+), name=(.+)><>(Count|Value)
  name: kafka_controller_$1_$2
- pattern : kafka.network<type=(.+), name=(.+)><>Value
  name: kafka_network_$1_$2
- pattern : kafka.network<type=(.+), name=(.+)PerSec, request=(.+)><>Count
  name: kafka_network_$1_$2_total
  labels:
    request: "$3"
- pattern : kafka.network<type=(.+), name=(\w+), networkProcessor=(.+)><>Count
  name: kafka_network_$1_$2
  labels:
    request: "$3"
  type: COUNTER
- pattern : kafka.network<type=(.+), name=(\w+), request=(\w+)><>Count
  name: kafka_network_$1_$2
  labels:
    request: "$3"
- pattern : kafka.network<type=(.+), name=(\w+)><>Count
  name: kafka_network_$1_$2
- pattern : kafka.server<type=(.+), name=(.+)PerSec\w*, topic=(.+)><>Count
  name: kafka_server_$1_$2_total
  labels:
    topic: "$3"
- pattern : kafka.server<type=(.+), name=(.+)PerSec\w*><>Count
  name: kafka_server_$1_$2_total
  type: COUNTER

- pattern : kafka.server<type=(.+), name=(.+), clientId=(.+), topic=(.+), partition=(.*)><>(Count|Value)
  name: kafka_server_$1_$2
  labels:
    clientId: "$3"
    topic: "$4"
    partition: "$5"
- pattern : kafka.server<type=(.+), name=(.+), topic=(.+), partition=(.*)><>(Count|Value)
  name: kafka_server_$1_$2
  labels:
    topic: "$3"
    partition: "$4"
- pattern : kafka.server<type=(.+), name=(.+), topic=(.+)><>(Count|Value)
  name: kafka_server_$1_$2
  labels:
    topic: "$3"
  type: COUNTER

- pattern : kafka.server<type=(.+), name=(.+), clientId=(.+), brokerHost=(.+), brokerPort=(.+)><>(Count|Value)
  name: kafka_server_$1_$2
  labels:
    clientId: "$3"
    broker: "$4:$5"
- pattern : kafka.server<type=(.+), name=(.+), clientId=(.+)><>(Count|Value)
  name: kafka_server_$1_$2
  labels:
    clientId: "$3"
- pattern : kafka.server<type=(.+), name=(.+)><>(Count|Value)
  name: kafka_server_$1_$2

- pattern : kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+)PerSec\w*><>Count
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3_total
- pattern : kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+)PerSec\w*, topic=(.+)><>Count
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3_total
  labels:
    topic: "$4"
  type: COUNTER
- pattern : kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+)PerSec\w*, topic=(.+), partition=(.+)><>Count
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3_total
  labels:
    topic: "$4"
    partition: "$5"
  type: COUNTER
- pattern : kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+)><>(Count|Value)
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3_$4
  type: COUNTER
- pattern : kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+), (\w+)=(.+)><>(Count|Value)
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3_$6
  labels:
    "$4": "$5"
```

Comment: Nice answer, allthough it's not exactly what OP asked for. The jmx_prometheus_javaagent will expose JMX metrics via HTTP in a format suitable for prometheus. This could be sufficient for what OP needs, but if he wants to use a JMX client, he'll need access to the actual JMX_PORT.

Comment: Oh, right. This may be used as a workaround.

Comment: The same question could be asked - how would OP know what port the exporter is available on? You've shown 7080, but could be anything, or nothing

Comment: The port of the prometheus exporter is part of the -javaagent cli option.

Comment: @GeertPt Yes, but assuming Kafka was installed by "someone else", that still requires communication with that person rather than being able to query directly out of Zookeeper, as indicated by OP